# Keytool command for Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, debian, raspberry-pi, change-password

I am using Raspberry Pi (Debian 3.1.9+ armv6l linux) and javaSE 7 and I am trying to change my trustore password by keytool but keytool command is not working So can you please tell me how can i change my trustore password in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Oracle Java SE 8 for ARM and it worked without any problems. First, create a keystore if you have not done that:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias tstkey
```

Once the keystore is setup, you can change the password using

```
keytool -storepasswd
```

If you see the following error message when changing the password, it means that the keystore has not been created before, and you have to use `keytool -genkey ...` to create it:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ keytool -storepasswd
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /home/pi/.keystore
```